# Adobe Flex Framework Diagram wallpaper

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flex3

do anybody have flex framework diagram which can be put as wallpaper in my machine. I got some at [here](http://wearekorean.co.kr/zbxe/files/attach/images/138/703/025/Adobe%20Flex%20Framework%203.0%20Additional%20Classes.jpg), but when i put it, it became unreadable. do anybody has that, so that it can be used as a quick reference.

regards, PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Adobe account, you can order your Flex API posters from Adobe.  If you don't have an account already, you should be able to create one and then fill out the form to receive your posters.

[Flex API Posters](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=posters)

Comment: Hi bryan, thanks for that. is there anyway i will get a soft copy of the same poster?